# Write last() function inside select query in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT hr.*,hr_leave.*,(SELECT LAST(hr_leave.fromdate) AS lastdate from hr_leave)
FROM hr
INNER JOIN hr_leave
ON hr.id=hr_leave.hrid
WHERE hr.oid=4 AND  hr.ouid=1
ORDER BY
hr_leave.hrid,hr_leave.fromdate
GROUP BY hr_leave.from
```

Can anyone tell me the error in this query? I keep getting:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(hr_leave.fromdate) AS lastdate from hr_leave)
>       FROM hr
>       INNER JOIN hr_lea' at line 1

Comment: to get last value of column use following: SELECT column_name FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name DESC
LIMIT 1;

Comment: i want to get a last value of a previous row ,let's say i'm getting a  values from 3rd row ,and also want to get a value from a 2nd row as well

Comment: @sasy did you find answer of you question? i mean there is not last function in aggregation function list.

Comment: yes,thank you very much @Amit

Comment: @sasy gr8, you can use alternate queries to get last record,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like last in mysql now, No,
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

so to get desired result, please use query. SELECT column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name DESC LIMIT 1